# Can less retain colored output?

Tags: colors, less

Can I get less not to monochrome its output?

E.g., the output from `git diff` is colored, but `git diff | less` is not.

Comment: possibly the same on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/117841/get-colors-in-less-command#comment119912_117841

Comment: Related but not identical isssue. The link is about `less` only.

Answer (score 693, accepted):

Use:

```
git diff --color=always | less -r
```

`--color=always` is there to tell `git` to output color codes even if the output is a pipe (not a tty). And `-r` is there to tell `less` to interpret those color codes and other escape sequences. Use `-R` for ANSI color codes only.

Comment: Excellent! Can I translate this to a "git config --global" command?

Comment: @ripper234. With recent gits, `git config color.ui true` should be enough to obtain colored output, *and* to automatically run a pager for long outputs.

Comment: True enough, I was actually using something similar but not quite like it. Thanks anyway for the great answer.

Comment: @ripper234 you can set an alias for this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50007/24272

Comment: In parallel to this Q/A, `watch --color 'git diff --cached --color=always'` and its friends can bring you some additional awesomeness.

Comment: Isn't using `less -R` better (or `export LESS=R` in `/etc/profile`)? Why would you allow it to display anything but ANSI "color" escape sequences? Also, the man page says `Warning: when the -r option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual appearance of the screen (since this depends on how the screen  responds  to each  type  of control character).  Thus, various display problems may result, such as long lines being split in the wrong place.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18304605/520567 -- i.e. `-c color.status=always` for forced colors on `git status`

Comment: And if you forgot to specify `-r` option, you can just type "-r" at the `less` prompt. This of course works with most or all less options (i.e., `-i` to turn on ignorecase).

Comment: `grep --color=always` works the same way.  This is not part of this question or answer, but I got here from googling about that question so there it is.

Comment: Also works with `ack` by specifying `ack --color`. Thanks!

Comment: I have `alias diff='/usr/bin/diff --color=always '` and `alias less='/usr/bin/less -r '` and the output is initially coloured but after paging it goes back to mono.

Comment: This does not work for `git status`. For that one should use `git config --global color.status always`.

Comment: I found a much easier way for git: using the `--paginate` option - e.g. `git --paginate diff` or `git --pagine status -vv`

Comment: Doesn't work for `git status`

Comment: I much prefer `-R` because it only effects color control characters. With `-r` even newlines are always printed literally so `-S` no longer works

Comment: In `~/.bashrc` put `alias less='less -r'`.

Comment: It's sad that I want to use `cut` instead of `less`. Can less specify how many columns to print?

Comment: you should use -R  because -r will not work correctly when scrolling.. it will not keep the order of escape sequences and your terminal will end up screwed.

Answer (score 81):

Another option would be to enable colors and use 'less -r' as your pager.

```
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global core.pager 'less -r'
```

This results in

```
[color]
    ui = true
[core]
    pager = less -r
```

in your ~/.gitconfig

For more information see the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git).

Possible values for `color.ui` can be found in the man page of git-config. The output of `man git-config | grep "color.ui$" -A8` is

```
color.ui
    This variable determines the default value for variables such as color.diff and
    color.grep that control the use of color per command family. Its scope will expand as
    more commands learn configuration to set a default for the --color option. Set it to
    false or never if you prefer Git commands not to use color unless enabled explicitly
    with some other configuration or the --color option. Set it to always if you want all
    output not intended for machine consumption to use color, to true or auto (this is the
    default since Git 1.8.4) if you want such output to use color when written to the
    terminal.
```

Comment: Using Git 2.11, I found that `color.ui true` did not work with a pager, but `color.ui always` did. This may have changed since the answer was posted.

Comment: This option (to enable colors and use 'less -r' as your pager by default) with `color.ui true` do work for comands like `git -p diff` and `git -p status` (where `-p` means pipe all output into $PAGER, by default it's `less`) even for rather old versions of git (for example, Git 1.7.1).
But you still need `color.ui always` (which tells git to output color codes "even if the output is a pipe (not a tty)") to get colored output when you directly specify `git status | less -r` or `git diff | less -r`.
When you specify output redirection explicitly, you won't see the output after quit from pager.

Comment: `git status | less` and `git -p status` seem to behave exactly the same for me when `color.ui always` is set - but since the former both requires a discouraged configuration option and is longer, I'll simply go with the latter ^^

Answer (score 42):

Use `-r` (`--raw-control-chars`) option to less, or also `-R` (only ANSI escape sequences).

I have an alias for this in `~/.bashrc`

```
alias rless='less -r'
```

Comment: Actually I just did `alias less='less -r'`. Any reason not to?

Comment: @ripper234: I vaguely remember there could be cases when using `-r` when not needed can lead to visualization problem.

Comment: For instance, when you pipe `ack` with `less -r` you lose a  carriage return

Comment: You can just use `\less` if visualization messes up.

Comment: Uh, you don’t have to alias `less` to anything, just set the `$LESS` environment variable to the set of flags you always want to provide to `less`, e.g. `export LESS='-MRq -z-2 -j2’`

Comment: `less -R` is better for just colored output - it allows things like `-S` (chop long lines) to continue working.

Answer (score 30):

In case anyone is interested in paging a json with `jq` and `less` it can be achieved using:

```
jq -C <jq args> file.json | less -R
```

e.g.

```
jq -C . file.json | less -R
```

Source: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/764#issuecomment-95355331

Answer (score 27):

Also `tree` has an option to force colors on:

```
tree -C | less -r
```

And so on for `ls`:

```
ls -lR --color | less -r
```

Answer (score 19):

I know this is old and many have already provided the right answer but I would like to add that it is always better to use `less -R` and not `less -r` if you only need ANSI colors as `-r` may cause problems in displaying the characters.

From the manual:

> ```
>   -r or --raw-control-chars
>          Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.   The  default
>          is  to display control characters using the caret notation; for
>          example, a control-A (octal 001) is displayed as  "^A".   Warn‐
>          ing:  when the -r option is used, less cannot keep track of the
>          actual appearance of the screen (since this depends on how  the
>          screen responds to each type of control character).  Thus, var‐
>          ious display problems may result,  such  as  long  lines  being
>          split in the wrong place.
>
>   -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
>          Like  -r,  but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in
>          "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the  screen  appearance  is  maintained
>          correctly  in  most  cases.   ANSI "color" escape sequences are
>          sequences of the form:
>
>               ESC [ ... m
> ```

Answer (score 17):

Just to add another version on the "use `less -r`":

Use the environment variable `LESS` with the value r (or add r to whatever it already is)

E.g., as I use it in my `.bashrc`:

```
export LESS=-Xr
```

[The X stops](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) the screen from clearing when exiting less.

Comment: unfortunately -X also breaks mouse scrolling for me :c

Answer (score 3):

I believe the ultimate solution is to use `unbuffer` which can be found in the `expect` package.

In essence, you retain `git diff` color by running the command as follows:

```
unbuffer git --no-pager diff [some_file] | less -r
```

You have to use `--no-pager` as otherwise the command hangs.

I'd have liked to take credit for this but [jcubic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386752/60733) got there long before me.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to achieve this for `yq` to parse YAML files because I have to work with large YAML files on a daily basis. A quick look at the `man yq` confirmed that `-C` flag is also available for `yq`. The following worked for me.

```bsh
kustomize build k8s/overlays/dev | yq eval -C | less -r
```

I added and alias in my `~/.zshrc` file for convenience

```bsh
alias yqlc='yq eval -C | less -r'
```

Now

```bsh
kustomize build k8s/overlays/dev | yqlc
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @gerald-senarclens-de-grancy

[Gerald answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/can-less-retain-colored-output/62850#62850)

Helped me a lot. I only change `less -r`by `more`, this keep changes on terminal.

```
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global core.pager 'more'
```

This results in

```
[color]
    ui = true
[core]
    pager = more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting colored output from `less`, you might be using the one from busybox. Install the real [less](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243500/busybox-pager-with-color-capability) instead.