# How to create an alias that takes an argument in KornShell

Tags: alias, ksh

I am trying to create an alias which when given some argument will look for the folder with contains the argument as pattern. Let the alias name be `gohf`.

Now, I will be using this alias like `gohf <some-pattern>`, for eg. `gohf testing`. Now this should look for a folder that contains “testing” in its name and take me to that folder in the last step.

Following is what I could think of.

```
alias gohf='cd `find . -type d | grep testing`';
```

The above alias works when the pattern is always “testing”.
How can I modify so that if the alias is used as say `gohf game`, then the alias should take me to the folder that contains game in its name.

**Note**:

Shell: ksh

I am assuming that there is only one folder for each pattern I input.

Comment: See if you can get an answer from [Is it possible to use a parameter within an alias command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/is-it-possible-to-use-a-parameter-within-an-alias-command). Or shorter: no way, that is out of aliases' scope. Use a function instead.

Comment: Any particular reason to not use a function instead? 
    gohf() {
 cd ´find . -type d | grep $1´
    }

Excuse me for using the wrong " ` "

Comment: piping `find` to `grep` is bad practice.  the `-name` or `-iname` flags do the same thing and can handle regex as well

Comment: @MartínCanaval: If I use `gohf() { cd ´find . -type d | grep $1´ }`  ...I copied this function to my .profile...but I get the `gohf{: command not found
`

Comment: did you make sure the .profile file was sourced? IE, did you start a fresh session on a new TTY or logout and log back in? Or safer to add it to `.kshrc` and do a `. ./kshrc`, just to test it. Also, try with what the guy down there suggested in his answer.

Comment: Yes ,I have done that.I also use `ksh .profile`

Comment: Please ignore ...I made some manual mistake.

Comment: @MartínCanaval, instead of posting single quote instead of backtick, better use `$(…)` in your code: `gohf() { cd $(find . -type d | grep $1); }`.

Comment: What difference would that make ? Any advantage of using `()` ?

Comment: @g4ur4v, 1) [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff), 2) `$(…)` doesn't conflict with Markdown syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As manatwork said in the comment you should use a function instead to handle arguments better.

```
gohf(){
  cd $(find . -type d -iname "$1" | sed 1q)
}
```

There is no need to pipe the results of `find` to `grep` as using the flag `-name` or `-iname` does the same thing.  Then we pipe the whole thing to `sed` so that we only `cd` to the first "hit" if there are multiple.

In the case that you want to be able to handle multiple `find` "hits" you should do something like this:

```
gohf(){
  select dir in $(find . -name "$1" -type d)
  do
    cd $dir
    break
  done
}
```

Comment: How do I use this function in my shell.when I copy this to `.profile`,I get this error `gohf{: command not found`

Comment: @g4ur4v because your `.profile` is read once when the shell is executed you just need to `exec ksh` to get it to read the new copy by executing a new shell without forking the process

Comment: I am getting that error after logging into the account after making changes to `.profile`.Even if I use `exec ksh`,I get the same error.

Comment: Please ignore ...I made some manual mistake.

Comment: Not "better", aliases _don't_ take arguments at all.

Comment: `alias psg='ps -ef | grep '` sort of takes an argument (ie. `psg root`).  if you look at the other previous comments you will see us call things like this "arguments" though we know theyre not actual arguments