# Busybox pager with color capability?

Tags: colors, git, less, busybox, pager

I [asked on Superuser](https://superuser.com/q/998378/504387) about colors for `git log` in MobaXterm (on Windows), but it turned out that the problem wasn't MobaXterm—it's the lack of a `-R` flag in busybox's `less`.

It would help my workflow greatly if I could see colors in the output of git's usual commands—git log, git diff, etc.

My terminal itself is capable of colors, as I verified by setting `git config color.ui always` and running `git log | cat`.  However I can't use cat as my pager, for obvious reasons.

Is there an alternative to `less -R` that works on busybox?  Or some other pager I could install and use with git for color capabilities?

Comment: If all else fails, I'm actually considering installing vagrant and running a virtual box...which of course would be complete overkill just for a colored pager!  (Though it does have other advantages.)

Comment: can you install GNU less on your windows box?  or whatever it is you're using MobaXterm to connect to.

Comment: Boy did that make me feel silly :)  `type less` returned `less is aliased to '/bin/busybox.exe less'`.  Running `apt-get install less` handled it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing GNU `less` on your Windows box.  That should fix it.