# less colored output with word-wrap disabled

Tags: colors, less, scrolling

**TL;RD** `less -S -R` gives colored output but lines still wrapped to next line.

I'm requesting a http service (instagram api) which gives me json encoded data. I use `prettyjson` from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettyjson) to see colored output. But some lines are too long, so they are wrapped by terminal. I want to enable horizontal scroll by using `less`. Horizontal scroll works by arrow keys, but lines still wrapped to next line

<sub>Look at last lines with `thumbnail_src` and `display_src`</sub>
[image: screenshot of termnal app in OSX]
<sub>*screenshot of terminal app in OSX*</sub>

Comment: The title of that window shows you're using `less -R`, not `less -RS`. If you type `-S` from within less, does that remove the wrapping?

Answer (score 1):

By reading unix stackexchange I found the answer:

> Warning: when the -r option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual appearance of the screen (since this depends on how the screen responds to each type of control character). Thus, various display problems may result, such as long lines being split in the wrong place.

[link to comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/can-less-retain-colored-output#comment217575_19320)

Comment: `less -R` is supposed to be the fix to that. _Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly in most cases._ `(repeat 10 seq 100 | paste -sd - -) | grep --color=always '[0-9]' | less -RS` (zsh syntax) works OK for me. Possibly `less` cannot determine the width of your terminal.