# How to display color by piping command to less?

Tags: colors, less

When I use:

```
msgattrib --untranslated pl.po
```

to see untranslated strings from po file I've got strings in color, but not when I use:

```
msgattrib --untranslated pl.po | less
```

Comment: Assumed you missed a word; revert the edit if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for the edit I don't remember, but probably wanted to add line after the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`msgattrib` display colors only if executed from real terminal. You can use `unbuffer` command that's part of `expect` to make `msgattrib` think that it's executed from real terminal and then use `-r` option to handle ANSI escapes in `less`:

```
unbuffer msgattrib --untranslated pl.po | less -r
```

You can do that in any command that produce colors (ANSI escapes codes) based on existance of tty.

Answer (score 1):

From the less man page:

```
-R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly in most  cases.
```

The simplest way to have this enabled all the time is to set the `LESS` environment variable in your `.profile` or `.login` script. I use both `-R` and `-X` (which prevents the screen being cleared when less exits).

Comment: This don't change behavior of msgattrib that will not produce the colors if you pipe to less, -R will not change anything because there will be no escapes codes.

Comment: @jcubic's comment here is correct, but this answer does provide that you won't need the `-r` or `-R` flag when piping output from `unbuffer` as in @jcubic's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To show less with colors: `less -R <text-file>`
Or config your less as an alias like `alias less='less -R'` inside the `~/.bashrc`

Comment: This just duplication of accepted and upvoted answer. Add answer only if yours is not already added.

Comment: this is how to config it as always (with alias)

Comment: This is not question about aliases. Only about less and it's already answered with same code as your answer.